# Handle Enter key in CoreUI's CInput control

Tags: vue.js, core-ui

My Vue.js view consists of a single CInput and a single send button (CButton). As a comfort feature, I want to trigger the send method, when the user hits the Enter key as long as the text input has focus. According to the [official documentation](https://coreui.io/vue/docs/components/form-components.html#cinput-and-ctextarea-api), only the `@input`, `@update:value` and `@change` events can be used by this control. But I haven't found any clue about the pressed key.

I tried using the `@input` handler, which offers two arguments. The first one is the new value itself, and the second one is an event argument, but I can't find any hint of a key code there.

How can I find out, which key the user pressed and call my send method in case of the Enter key (keycode 13)?

Answer (score 0):

v-on:keypress.enter="your method"